# How can I get information if a specific cookie (by search of its value) exists or not in JS?

Tags: javascript, cookies, authentication

How can I get information if a specific cookie (by search of its value) exists or not in JS?
There is a cookie named 'XYZ' and its value is 'ZYX',
 how can I check if the cookie exists or not by its value?
I dont want to use Jquery
Thanks.

Comment: What if you have several cookies with the same value?

Comment: I dont have, there is a reason why I asked that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function returns `true` if any cookie with value `v` exists and `false` otherwise.

```
function check(v) {
  return !!document.cookie.split(/;\s*/).filter(function(c) {return v === c.split(/=/)[1]}).length;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much!